# How can I visually distinguish Activities in ForEach loops in DataFactory Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working with Azure **DataFactory Templates** and trying to give each activity a unique **name** in a **ForEach** loop so that I can distinguish them in the pipeline run.

I am copying files from BlobStorage into CosmosDB collections. If I execute my script I only see identical entries for each activity and do not see which collections are being migrated:

[image]

This is what I want to use, but it gives me an InvalidTemplate error:

```
{
    "name": "ForEach_894",
    "type": "ForEach",
    "typeProperties": {
        "items": {
            "value": "@activity('GetBlobStorageFileNames').output.childItems",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "@{item().name}",
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The template validation failed: 'The name of template action '@{item().name}Scope' at line '1' and column '20385' is not defined or not valid
```

My script works if I use a fixed string:

```
"activities": [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        ...
    }
```

Maybe I can add extra columns like in this case:

[image]

Comment: You can see all the function in the Azure template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions) and I don't find the for each loop.

Comment: @CharlesXu ForEach-Loops are defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. You cannot see it while the activity is running, but once the activity has finished the columns (Source, Destination) will be added.

[image]

Just specify them in your ARM Template, like this:

```
{
    "name": "ForEach_894",
    "type": "ForEach",
    "typeProperties": {
        "items": {
            "value": "@activity('GetBlobStorageFileNames').output.childItems",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "@{item().name}",
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "@{item().name}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "@{item().name}"
                    }
                ]
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```